# How to run native Windows 10 apps on startup?

Tags: windows-10

My goal is: **run some native Windows 10 apps at startup time**

The way I would do it with an installable app is right click on the app from then start menu, go to containing folder and then make a shortcut to the executable file   in **shell:startup** but there is no such an option to go to **containing** folder for apps installed from **Microsoft store**

Comment: that's right. how do I remove my own question?

Comment: @dragonmnl - Questions that receive answers, which are upvoted, cannot be deleted.  So if you want to delete this question, you start by deleting your answer, then delete your question.

Answer (score 0):

While writing the question I realized that in fact there is the folder **shell:appsfolder** (still from **Windows+R**) to achieve the same purpose for native/store apps